# iOS app crash after updating AdMob from v7.4.1 to the latest v7.8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I have an iOS app than I begun to code 4 years ago. Every year after the new iOS release, I update my app with the new iOS and the new AdMob SDK.

But this year I'm getting crazy! When I change the GoogleMobileAds.framework to the new version, the app crash after any call to GADRequest. Even if I try to get the version with

NSLog(@"Google Mobile Ads SDK version: %@", [GADRequest sdkVersion]);

I've got a crash. Of course, I have -ObjC in the compiler flags. I've tried to change the use of the framework standalone to use Pods, but I always get the same error. I attach you the stack:

```
016-10-02 19:18:55.062 TheNameOfMayApp[13162:7700615] -[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00656c646e696b6
2016-10-02 19:18:55.073 TheNameOfMayApp[13162:7700615] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00656c646e696b6'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104dfe34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010478021e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e6df34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d83c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d83798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d7b044 -[NSSet initWithArray:] + 36
    6   TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100fe3c70 GADIsAtLeastVersion + 11841
    7   TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100fe177d GADIsAtLeastVersion + 2382
    8   TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100fe15d9 GADIsAtLeastVersion + 1962
    9   TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100fe142b GADIsAtLeastVersion + 1532
    10  TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100f6b5e8 GADiTunesMetadataForFileAtPath + 2401
    11  TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100f76ba8 GADGIDSignInInstance + 3464
    12  TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100fafe77 GADDispatchAsyncSafeMainQueue + 45
    13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104780efa CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 19
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104781126 _class_initialize + 554
    15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104787c1d lookUpImpOrForward + 176
    16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104797554 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
    17  TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100ea421b -[MainViewController PonPublicidadAdMob] + 59
    18  TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100ea393a -[MainViewController MuestraPublicidad] + 122
    19  TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100ea4a69 -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] + 73
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010248b06d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010248b4a0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    22  TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100e96346 -[TheNameOfMayAppAppDelegate preparaPantallaInicialConiOS6] + 886
    23  TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100e95ddd -[TheNameOfMayAppAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 285
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001022e068e -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001022e2013 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236
    26  UIKit                               0x00000001022e83b9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    27  UIKit                               0x00000001022e5539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a6c276b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a6c25e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    30  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a6c296d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104da3311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d8859c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d87a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d87494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    35  UIKit                               0x00000001022e3db6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    36  UIKit                               0x00000001022e9f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    37  TheNameOfMayApp                     0x0000000100e93d1e main + 62
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001065c168d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Can you help me, please???? I've spent two weeks with no fortune trying all the similar "solutions" here in StackOverflow and in Google Groups.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What's the instance of `0xa00656c646e696b6` ? Did you print it out ? Is it a Tagged Pointer String ? [If it's attempting to create a Tagged Pointer String that has more than 60 bytes, it will fail](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for `NSTaggedPointerString` find out where you are calling `[NSTaggedPointerString count]`. Now google `NSTaggedPointerString` and check if `count` method exists or not. If not then find out other way providing `count` method

Comment: I don't call anything but [GADRequest sdkVersion] or [GADRequest request]. The calls of the stack are produced by the GoogleMobileAds.framework itself

Comment: Then its bug in the framework you are using, you should contact vendor with this crash report.

Also read the vendor documentation, you might be using it incorrectly, may be you need to initialize something before calling `request` method. Read their documentation

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is the vendor is Google, and noone apears to have this bug! I've read the docs many times. I've tried everithing before posting here :-(

Comment: If its Google then problem seems be your code :). That was joke (most probably not), but you should open bug with Google.

Comment: Thank you again. I think is a google problem because with v7.4.1 and before, the code works, but with the new library, crash. Pherhaps is something to change in the configuration files, but I'm very lost! I'm going to find out how to write google directly ;-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes as an Array in your .plist file.
then add required keys inside it as defined below!

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>add required key here</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Thank you all. Finally, I've created a new blank project and recoded again, and it works perfectly... The same code... Ok, I supouse there is something diferent but I cannot see it ;-)